# Javascript - comparision projects using object keys

Tags: javascript

I found the method to get all properties of object:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    const val = obj[key];
    // use val
}
```

But how can I compare 2 objects if these objects have a boolean field for each field to mark that object is different to the comparision?

```
export class MyObject {
   fieldOne: number;
   fieldOneChanged: boolean;
   fieldTwo: number;
   fieldTwoChanged: boolean;
   // and many more fields
}
```

And I compare it the following:

```
if (myObj1.fieldOne != myObj2.fieldOne) {
    myObj2.fieldOneChanged = true;
}
```

And now I wonder how can I user Object.keys() to reduction comparision and make it more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `key` variable to compare the properties of the two objects.

```
for (const key of Object.keys(myObj1)) {
    if (myObj1[key] != myObj2[key]) {
        myObj2[key + "Changed"] = true;
    }
}
```